# Data Binding Help WPF VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

Ok, so I have been trying to iron out this data binding for a while now and every time I think I get it, it doesn't work.  Please tell me where I am going wrong.  Let me know if you need more info, but basically, for right now, I have this as my wAddClient.xaml.vb:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class WAddClient
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    DataContext = newClient
    newClient = New Client()

End Sub

Private _newClient As Client
Public Property newClient As Client
    Get
        Return _newClient
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Client)
        _newClient = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("newClient")
    End Set
End Property

Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub
End Class
```

Then this is what I am trying to do as far as the binding, this is the XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Name="txtFirstName" Margin="0,0,5,0">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Source="Me" Path="newClient.first_name" Mode="TwoWay" 
                 ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

So as you can guess, client has a property first_name that I want to bind.  Here is partial code for the client class.

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Client
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Implements IDataErrorInfo

'Constructors
Public Sub New()
    salutation = "Mr."
    first_name = "Kevin"
    last_name = "Tester"
    email = ""
    primary_phone = ""
    address_1 = ""
    city = ""
    state_code = ""
    zip_code = ""
    address_2 = ""
    secondary_phone = ""
    fax = ""
End Sub
```

So I do not understand what I am doing wrong.  Please help.

Comment: Is `first_name` a Property, or is it a field?  You can't bind to a field.  Also... you don't actually explain what goes wrong other than "it doesn't work" - more detail would help.  In particular, the Output window in VS will show you a binding error that is usually very helpful in diagnosing these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your binding: `Source="Me"` that is wrong.

Remove that and assign an instance of a Client to the DataContext. The Binding's Path will be relative to that object.

Also make sure the Client class uses public properties that will be bound to. Fields do not support binding.

Comment: Nice, I spent 2 hours trying different combinations.  For anyone trying to use part of the code in the future, I switched the lines as suggested below.
    DataContext = newClient    
    newClient = New Client()

and I change the databinding to this:
    <Binding Path="first_name" Mode="TwoWay" 
                         ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" 
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                </Binding>

Answer (score 2):

Sorry my VB.net skills are non existent. But lets try it anyway:

```
    DataContext = newClient
    newClient = New Client()
```

I think you should switch these two lines. Not sure how referencing in VB.net works tho.

Also you didn't mentioned whats not working exactly. So i would suggest you download Snoop, to see if the DataContext is correct.